# VBA FindAll method in range with delete

Tags: vba, excel

Outcome : Find and Remove a value in a range and shift cells up.

Having some issues with an infinite loop in my code. I believe the problem might be with the LastCell.

I need to locate all the 0 in a range. Select, delete and shift cells up.

```
sub(FindAllDelete)

Dim EmptyCells As Range
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim FirstAddr As String

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F30:W1000")
Set LastCell = Range("W1000")
End With
Set EmptyCells = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F30:W1000").Find(What:="0", After:=LastCell)

If Not EmptyCells Is Nothing Then
    FirstAddr = LastCell.Address
End If

  Do Until EmptyCells Is Nothing
     Debug.Print EmptyCells.Address
     Set EmptyCells = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F30:W1000").FindNext(after=EmptyCells)
    If EmptyCells.Address = FirstAddr Then
  Exit Do
    End If
    Loop
    EmptyCells.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
```

Comment: you need to define which worksheet, like `Worksheets("Sheet1")`. But you confised a lot of things here, what exactly are you trying to achieve ? remove all "0" from `Range("F30:W1000")` ?

Comment: hi, i forgot to add the worksheet in the post indeed, but it is in my code. Yes I would like to Find all 0s and then delete the cell and shift them up.

Comment: all the other cells inside the range have values inside them ? or you have some empty cells ?

Comment: the other cells are not empty. they have values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the answer given by @Shai Rado as it doesn't involve any looping, but saying that I wrote the code so I'm going to post it....

This way unions all the 0 ranges, or you could delete them as you find them and just continue the loop until `EmptyCells Is Nothing`.

```
Public Sub FindAllDelete()

    Dim EmptyCells As Range
    Dim AllCells As Range
    Dim FirstAddr As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F30:W1000")
        Set EmptyCells = .Find(0)

        If Not EmptyCells Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddr = EmptyCells.Address
            Do
                If EmptyCells.Address = FirstAddr Then
                    Set AllCells = EmptyCells
                Else
                    Set AllCells = Union(AllCells, EmptyCells)
                End If

                Set EmptyCells = .FindNext(EmptyCells)

            Loop While EmptyCells.Address <> FirstAddr
        End If

    End With

    AllCells.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp

End Sub
```

Comment: also nice (thought of doing this as a second option, but you beat me to it)

Comment: not only I +1 your answer, but also the PO has accepted it as answer, positive people are rewarded :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `EmptyCells.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp` is placed outside of the `Do` loop, so it will not be executed during the looping over the cells.  Spotting these kinds of errors is made easier if you indent your code consistently, like e.g.:

```
Do Until EmptyCells Is Nothing
    Debug.Print EmptyCells.Address
    Set EmptyCells = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F30:W1000").FindNext(after=EmptyCells)
    If EmptyCells.Address = FirstAddr Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
EmptyCells.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
```

Formatting it like this shows you in one look that the .Delete is not happening to all cells but only once in the end.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will work properly in case all cells in Range("F30:W1000") have values inside them (no blank values in the begining).

First, replace all cells inside the range that have "0" inside them with "", so now they are actualy blank.

Now, using the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` we can set another range, and delete all of them at once.

**Note**: like I wrote in the begining, this will work only if all cells inside the range have values, if there are empty cells (which the PO said there are none) they will be deleted too.

**Code**

```
Sub FindAllDelete()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim EmptyCells As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    Set Rng = .Range("F30:W1000")

    With Rng
        .Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
    End With

    Set EmptyCells = Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    EmptyCells.Delete xlShiftUp
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: (comment applied only to 1st version) Note that this also deletes any cells that were empty previous to this; e.g. it deletes all '0' cells and all empty cells.

Comment: see my note above ^

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without VBA, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to replace the 0's with a blank and then delete the blanks using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> selecting blanks and deleting

Comment: Feels like I'm plus 1'ing everyone today.  Is a good solution if you're doing it infrequently or don't need to trust someone else to do it (you know the ones - they're good at Excel because they saw a chart once).